# JSON Object With or Without Quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to learn JSON, i learned that any javascript object with the key in double quotes are considered as JSON object.

And i constructed this object

```
var jstr1 = {"mykey": "my value"};
```

But when i try to parse using JSON.parse(jstr1), i got the following error. see the screenshot.

[image]

But when i try to parse this

```
var jstr = '{"mykey": "my value"}';,
```

i got the success, see the screenshot. i got confused with this. Please explain me why this happens. what is the difference between the two forms.

And when i got JSON as a response from any services, how it would look like, whether it will be in form of `jstr` or `jstr1`

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As @ComFreek sais, if you already have the `Hash` what do you expect to obtain from parsing it?

Comment: First one is an object. Second is a string, a JSON to be precise. JSON.parse works on strings, not objects.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are creating a Javascript `Object`. If you want a JSON-*string* from it, use `JSON.stringify`.

So

```
const myObj = {mykey: "my value"};
const myObjJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Based on comments:
There is no such thing as a *JSON **Object***. There are JSON-strings, which can be `parsed` to Javascript Objects. Javascript Objects can be `stringified` to JSON strings. Within a JSON-string keys and values are quoted. So the result of the above is a *string* containing `'{"mykey":"my value"}'`.

Try parsing `myObjJSON` in your browser console (using: `JSON.parse(myObjJSON)`) and you get: `Object {mykey: "my value"}`.

Comment: @Kooilnc In ur answer, even though the mykey is not in double quotes as specified by JSON standards, it is converted to JSON string."var myObj = {mykey: "my value"}". I got the same result when i stringify the object with mykey with or without quotes.

Comment: @MohamedHussain The keys don't have to be enclosed by double quotes in *JavaScript*.

Comment: @ComFreek you are correct. keys not neccessary for to be in quotes but for JSON, they key needed to be in double quotes, i learned this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation?lq=1

Comment: @MohamedHussain: in a javascript `Object` there's no need for quoting key names, unless the key name contains spaces. Also check http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/cargo-culting-in-javascript/?utm_source=buffer

Comment: @Kooilnc you are correct javascript object key does not need quotes. My question is does JSON Object key requires double quotes?.

Comment: @Kooilnc: Thanks For mentioning there is no JSON Object. Normal Javascript object can be converted into JSON String. If normal Javascript object key, doesn't have double quotes when stringify to JSON string, double quotes is added in JSON string. If quotes is already present also same result when stringify from Javascript object to JSON string

Comment: It should be `'{"mykey":"my value"}'`. Can not edit ;)

Comment: Any idea of getting this kind of object ? ` {
  "year": 2019,
  "month": 2,
  "day": 26
}`  instead of  {
  year: "2019",
  month: "2",
  day: "26"
}

Comment: @DenukaNirmalee Not sure what you mean, but you can use a replacer function, something like `JSON.stringify({ "year": "2019", "month": "2", "day": "26" }, (key, value) => !isNaN(+value) ? +value : value)`

Comment: Thank you so much Kooilnc and do you know how to how to remove all the double quotes in that object. That means getting an object like { year: 2019, month: 2, day: 26}

Comment: @DenukaNirmalee Just surround the code with: `JSON.parse(...)`

Answer (score 6):

This code

```
var jstr1 = {"mykey": "my value"};
```

creates a JavaScript object using the *Object Literal Notation*.

For the difference between the *Object Literal Notation* and *JSON* (JON is short for *JavaScript object notation*), see here: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation?lq=1)

It makes logically no sense to pass this data to `JSON.parse()`.

The difference to your first variant (`var jstr = '{"mykey": "my value"}';`) is that it creates a 'raw' string. You cannot access anything on that string except the raw character sequences. Using `JSON.parse()` gives us a usable form (object) created from the string.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

This comes from the automatic string conversion of `jstr1`:

```
jstr1.toString();
// gives us [object Object]
// ----------↑
```

Answer (score 6):

You have some missunnderstanting for `JSON.parse`

```
JSON.parse takes string and parse it to JAVASCRIPT object
JSON.stringify takes an object and parse it to a string
```

thats why when you ran the following

```
JSON.parse('{"a":"b"}')
```

it worked because it expects a json string

but when you ran

```
JSON.parse({"a":"b"})
```

it didnt because the object was coverted to string which is

```
"[object Object]"
```

and here is the error where "[object Object]" is not valid syntax at letter `o`

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse() accepts a string and converts to JSON object, it doesnt take a javascript object as the parameter. Refer [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) It could give you the results as follows

```
JSON.parse('{}'); // {}
JSON.parse('true'); // true
JSON.parse('"foo"'); // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null'); // null
```

and do know that **If the string to parse is not valid JSON, a SyntaxError exception is thrown.** so this is how you get syntax error on jstr1 (It is not a JSON string)

Answer (score -9):

How about this:

```
MarahJSONObject gtp = new MarahJSONObject()
    gtp.put("ecomm_prodid", "123")
    gtp.put("ecomm_pagetype", "cart")
    gtp.put("ecomm_totalvalue", "19.99")

String r = gtp.toString()
    gtp.keySet().each {
        r = r.replace(/"${it}"/, it)
    }
    println r
```

then you will get:
{ecomm_pagetype:"cart",ecomm_prodid:"123",ecomm_totalvalue:"19.99"}

Comment: what even is this?? I don't see how this solves the problem at hand