# Some doubts about 2 different JSON formats

Tags: javascript, json

Maybe this is a trivial question.

I am looking into a **JSON** file I found something like this:

```
{
    localization_id: 2,
    local_user_id: 33,
    is_active: true,
    registration_date: 2017-09-13 12:05:21
}
```

When looking into another JSON file otherwise I found something like this:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0036,
    "cnt": 40,
}
```

Why in the second one the field name and some value are into the **""**? Is it irrelevant or have a meaning?

Comment: More https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201441/is-there-any-practical-reason-to-use-quoted-strings-for-json-keys

Comment: More https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635132/json-object-with-or-without-quotes

Comment: More https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067974/in-json-why-is-each-name-quoted

Comment: maybe you have a look into the standard: [ECMA 404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or at [json.org](http://json.org/)

Comment: First example is javscript object representation and not valid JSON and the 2nd example is valid JSON.